# double redirect mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to configure a .htaccess file to my webpage to make it work as i want, but after a lot of searching and trying to understand the documentation, my head is just confused about these mod_rewrite.

It looks like this:

root/index.php

root/application/-subfolders-

root/config/-files-

root/library/-files-

what i want is everything sent to the index.php file as a parameter like index.php?page=$i, so i can have links like www.mypage.com/foo/bar and my index.php handles it.
ALSO i want to have the www.mypage.com/js/*filename* be sent to a subfolder in application,
like root/application/javascripts/*filename*.

I just cant get this to work, tried different answer i found both here and other places.

.htaccess at is now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/js/ application/javascripts/ [L]
RewriteRule ^/js/(.*)$ application/javascripts/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^css/ application/css/ [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ application/css/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^images/ application/images/ [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ application/images/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I am thinking you don't want a [L] at the end of every condition. The first JS rule stops after that due to the [L], and you want it to bubble down to the next rule.

Comment: Pretty sure 1st RewriteRule may be the only one that is evaluated.

Comment: Seems to work with Tims answer, though the value with $_GET['page'] is empty in the php script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ application/javascripts/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ application/css/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ application/images/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: it partly works, though the parameter in the php file seems to be empty, cause when i do $_GET['page'] nothing prints, dunno if it is the php or the rewrite?

Comment: The index line assumes you are passing something to the url, like http://localhost/getMyFile, which would translate to index.php?page=getMyFile. I assume just accessing http://localhost/ is translating to index.php?page= (nothing passed to variable).

Comment: Try the `http://yoursite/testMyVariable` or similar to see what `$_GET['page']` does.

Comment: its still empty, i loaded the page with phpinfo() and found i can access the variable anyway, but still, should work with $_GET['page'],

QUERY_STRING = page=(empty),
REQUEST_URI = /www/testVar,
SCRIPT_NAME = /www/index.php

Comment: Got it to work with RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]